# How to check memory used by a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management

How do I check the memory used by a process at same instance. Input provided is process NAME or ID. Need to know the actual memory used by the process at runtime.
What command should I enter to get result.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164653/actual-memory-usage-of-a-process

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to find out the actual memory consumption for eg.
top (memory/cpu stats), free ( used/unused memory),mpstat ( cpu stats). Although,
I'd like to mention the following as it suits your requirement.

top p process_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
`ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use general and for particular user,

General: top
For Particular User: top -U username